# Greener way to design a PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers, rohs

Lets say we are designing a very simple PCB and there is a layer(s) where not much is going on, from an environmental perspective alone would it be better to leave the layer with a large ground copper solid area, so not much etcher acid is needed, or would the etched copper/acid be reused afterwards by the FAB?

Comment: What about the environmental issues of mining the copper? Disposing of the etching fluid?

Comment: Copper is already mined, but can it be reused by the FAB after it has been etched?
The real question would be what happens to the used etching fluid?

Comment: There are many other reasons as well to leave as much copper on the PCB as possible. It etches faster and uses less etchants so it is cheaper to manufacture, not to mention it enables a PCB design which works better (shielding, ground plane). It makes no sense to have just a few wires and etch most of the copper away.

Comment: No offence, but arguments like these are just silly. If you wish to actually make a difference for the environment, then go with halogen-free (RoHS) PCB, don't use flame retardants or conformal coating, and in particular always design in high efficiency switching regulators. I suspect that the biggest environment culprit by far in electronics design are all linear regulators wasting extreme amounts of energy for nothing.

Comment: I think the question is useful. When you make 10000 PCB a year, it can make a difference.

Comment: Produce in EU or USA in stead of China.

Answer (score 2):

With the price of copper where it is these days fabrication houses are recycling the etching
chemicals to recover the copper.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I wanted the OP to find out.

Comment: By any chance do you have a source or the name of the chemical process?

Comment: i searched "how is copper recovered from etchant"  and found this http://www.cemco.com/regen.htm (disclaimer: not a reccomendation) there are no doubt competing products